# I want to add navigation controller in tabbed Application

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am working on xcode4.3.2 and I have created tabbed Application 7 now i want to add navigation controller to it, can somebody help me???

Comment: what you have tried? There are a lot of tutorials already present for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `applicationDidFinishingLoading` of your `AppDelegate`:

```
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *myNav1=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
UINavigationController *myNav2=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myNav1, myNav2, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

Comment: This post helped me :) Thanks Mat

Answer (score 0):

they're lots of tutorial on Internet but here some issue :

Start to create your tabbed application

At every "1st view" of any tabs :

Editor / Embed - in / Navigation Controller